# How can I deal with ember-ajax raising an exception inside of a promise?

Tags: ember.js

When I validate on my backend it returns a 400. So I make a request like:

```
this.get('ajax').request('api/foo/', {
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  method: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

The problem is that ember-ajax will raise an exception from inside a promise. How can I deal with that? The 400 is intentional behavior, not an exception, I don't want to see it in my console and it seems to be breaking other parts of my app.

Comment: By `catch`ing the rejection?

Comment: @torazaburo - you should add it as an answer with a bit more detail.  It's correct, and if I answer the same thing it's definite bad karma on my part ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just handle the exception:

```
.request(...).then(null, error => {
    // here analyse error.
    // if its expected `return` something,
    // other wise `throw error` to rethrow the error.
});
```